# "In the past one and half years, Stack Overflow has lost 50% of its traffic."

Tags: discussion, statistics, recent-activity

In a [tweet](https://twitter.com/madiator/status/1683735923387936768) by [Mahesh Sathiamoorthy](https://smahesh.com), I saw a chart showing a substantial recent drop:

[image]

Two questions: (1) Is this accurate? (2) What does the analogous chart for MathOverflow show?

(I can't remember how to look at site analytics.)

Comment: A blind guess: infighting of the type that's been happening over there since circa Monica is a bad look, irrespective of how you look at it from the outside. I'm all for fighting the good fight, ra ra fight the power and all that, but it's... unseemly to allow things to devolve as far as they have over there, IMO.

Comment: I don't know how much we can or should disclose, but looking at the admin link provided by @D.W., there is a somewhat similar drop (although, obviously, the graph is more detailed and it is possible to make sense of the exact "fall"). Nevertheless, this means nothing, since it can very well be spammers not using the site as much, or bots not trying to spam the site, or whatever. Statistics without contexts are meaningless.

Comment: @D.W. According to the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/site-analytics), the link available to 10k+ users is: https://mathoverflow.net/site-analytics

Comment: according to this post, https://observablehq.com/@ayhanfuat/the-fall-of-stack-overflow, all three metrics of traffic, votes, and posts, are down over 50%. Surely that suggests it's not just fewer spammers

Comment: Somewhat related question (with your answer): [The number of on line users at a given moment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3356). In the answer here I have posted number of users who were "active" in some way (at least one post, at least one comment): [The number of MO users](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5579). (Naturally, this is different from traffic - where you're interested in visitors, including the people who only viewed some page on the site and did nothing else.)

Comment: In case some people are interested in stats about number of questions and answer, there are a few related questions: 
[Number of questions posed per day](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1182), 
[Does the number of answers really drop over years?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4505), 
[Slight downward trend in Q & A](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2876), etc.

In fact, back in 2013 a moderator (now a former moderator) suggested "having quarterly or annual usage reports" on MO: [What statistics would be interesting for a usage report?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/903)

Comment: The 20k site analytics for the time period suggest a small but noticeable decline in the number of posts and votes, and a massive sudden drop in traffic in spring 2022. The latter turns out to be the effect of [recategorizing the Google analytics cookies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047). Another change (with unclear effects on the statistics) was the switch to GA4 later the same year. In other words, the statistics are *bogus*. They cannot be meaningfully compared across longer time spans, as the methodology keeps changing.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the reputation threshold to see site analytics is 25k, not 10k or 20k, according to https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/site-analytics .

Comment: Now on Youtube, [heavily memeized](https://youtu.be/cXlxMP9PU8I)

Comment: @AsafKaragila  During the last 2 years, the participation of some mathematicians has decreased significantly. On the other hand  I thiunk  there are some  journal who do not accept a reference to MO  conversations. I think that MO  activities is  not  counted as a serious  math activity. To be honest , I had the hope to  find collaborators for  discussion on the  following  items  but no communication formed in this way(in MO).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219638/proposals-for-polymath-projects/264440#264440

Comment: I hope MO will be  more active similar to (say)  4 or 5 years ago

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I mean that no institute consider MO activities of a researcher as a  serious  research activity. So this reduce the motivation for spending a significant time in MO

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I think  that it would be  a  good idea to ask all well known specialist  in various area(Differential Geometry, Dynamical  system, PDF, foliation, algebras, etc) and  some previously  MO-active polymath researchers  to reconnect to MO and participate in MO actively again.

Comment: On way  to do that is to create some new questions in MO.

Comment: @Ali: I think it's a good idea to not bother people in general. People come and people go. It is the nature of communities, online ones in particular.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  It is not bothering people with asking them to join again, the people   who were very active in MO and they disconnect based on unknown reason.

Comment: @Ali: You don't seem to understand my point. You *don't know* why they stopped participating. It's their business, and if they want to rejoin, they will rejoin. Full stop. Anything beyond that is off-site harassment which we do not take lightly.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  In my  comments on this post there is no any evidence of "bothering" I  would appreciate if you explain why you are talking about bothering?

Comment: Any way the comment of qed in the following post is interesting some how similar to a point I mentioned in above

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow-or-papers-inspired-by-mathoverflow#comment3075_617

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: On twitter is correct, In a tweet is correct, On a tweet is incorrect. :-) But thanks for the poster's name.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Corrected!